# click callback looses context depending on var or let

Tags: javascript, jquery

If you try this code with "`let i`" it works, and with "`var i`" it doesn't work.

Can you explain me why?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (let i=0; i<20; i++) {
        $('<button />').append(i).appendTo('body').click(function() {
            console.log(i);
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`var` will declare it in the scope of the anonymous function passed to the ready method, meaning there can be only be one `i` in the anonymous function scope hence you are getting this issue, the last number that was updated for i is shown!. When you define with `let` its scope is limited to the block on which its defined, which is the `for loop`, hence it works fine. Hope this helps you!

For further info visit [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/difference-between-var-and-let-in-javascript/)

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (let i=0; i<20; i++) {
        $('<button />').append(i).appendTo('body').click(function() {
            console.log(i);
        });
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: "var will define the variable in the global scope"  — No, it won't. It will declare it in the scope of the anonymous function passed to the `ready` method.

Comment: @Quentin I understand now, `var` is function scoped, should have noted this, didn't notice the ready function though, have edited my answer!

Answer (score -1):

have you tried to use .on('click', function(){}) ?

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    for (let i=0; i<20; i++) {
        let button = $('<button />').append(i);
        button.appendTo('body');
        button.on('click', function() {
            console.log(i);
        });
    }
});
```

i think the button first have to be existing before assinging click action listener

Comment: You seem to have misunderstood the question completely.

Comment: oh, first reading helps :)